# How to replace setContentView in a fragment for SQLdatabase?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I created a separate fragment in which i want to have a database. The problem is that the fragment does not allow to have setContentView, although this is needed for the code later code in the lines under it. How can i fix this? Please help.

```
public class section_number1 extends Fragment{

View rootview;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_number1, container, false);
    return rootview;
}

DatabaseHelper myDb;
EditText editName, editSurname, editBalance;
Button btnAddData;
Button btnviewAll;

public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_section_number1);// <--NOT WORKING
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    editName = (EditText) editName.findViewById(R.id.editText_Name);
    editSurname = (EditText) editSurname.findViewById(R.id.editText_Surname);
    editBalance = (EditText) editBalance.findViewById(R.id.editText_Balance);
    btnAddData = (Button) btnAddData.findViewById(R.id.button_add);
    btnviewAll = (Button) btnAddData.findViewById(R.id.button_viewAll);
    AddData();
    viewAll();

}
```

Comment: that's not how they work: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

Comment: why do you need fragments if you have no basic knowledge on how to use them? just use activities and Activity#setContentView

Comment: @pskink stole my heart with that answer. Just like he say... you don't have a good knowledge with Fragments. Study a bit more or use Activities

Comment: @pskink There's a good chance this user is new to Android development. It would be better to point them in the direction of where they can get information for best practices of using fragments instead of calling them out on not having "basic knowledge".

Comment: @McAdam331 this is because 4/5 users of SO overuse Fragments adding them in transactions to simulate "navigation" and i dont want OP to follow that bad path

Comment: Well that sounds more polite than the phrasing you used the first time.

Comment: ok i was too explicit and rude,i am sorry for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, delete this from your onCreate():

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_section_number1);
```

Next, move the following from your onCreate():

```
myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
editName = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.editText_Name);
editSurname = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.editText_Surname);
editBalance = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.editText_Balance);
btnAddData = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.button_add);
btnviewAll = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.button_viewAll);
AddData();
viewAll();
```

...to your onCreateView() method:

```
rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_number1, container, false);
// move it here
return rootview;
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to point out that you're also referencing your views incorrectly.

Instead of this:

```
editName = (EditText) editName.findViewById(R.id.editText_Name);
```

It should be this:

```
editName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText_Name);
```

All your views in this case must be referenced from the view that contains them, which is the view you've named "rootView"... `rootView.findViewById(R.id.name_of_your_view);`

Comment: Thank you for the help! But this creates a : java.lang.NullPointerException at: 
editName = (EditText) editName.findViewById(R.id.editText_Name);

Comment: you need to use rootview as your view: editName = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.editText_Name); You need to study a little bit more about Fragments.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla What is meant by "are you for real?"? That is a simple mistake anyone could have made.

Comment: See my edited answer (and heed Mariano's advice above ;))